# What can be the topic of my assignment for presentation about overall computing performance?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu, performance, high-performance-computing

I have received the below question for presentation. It was random assignment, its not my field. What is this specifically in Computer Architecture?

> how CPU and GPU architecture, memory bandwidth/interfaces, and storage interfaces, all combine to contribute to overall computing performance?

How and where can I get the material for its preparation? Any recommendation?

I am trying the following material (Chapter 1 & 2) if its right for above topic?

https://nap.nationalacademies.org/catalog/12980/the-future-of-computing-performance-game-over-or-next-level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topic cover broad range of work, It should start with

1- CPU-GPU Architecture, you can compare the latest one with the previous one in comparison section and show how it contribute towards the performance. Performance is not only based on CPU-GPU, next point should be

2- SDRAM , explain the concept of SDRAM, SDR SDRAM, DDR SDRAM, again you can compare DDR4 with DDR5

3- M.2 SSD NVMe, explain about utilizing the full capacity of SSD, you can compare it with SATA 3.0 and AHCI

4- PCIe, again compare it with PCIe 5.0 with PCIe 4.0

5- Explain about the motherboard.

All these major component contribute towards the performance of the system.